# Don't push properties of an element which type is null

Tags: javascript

How can I push only properties to array which type is not null?
I have the following code:

```
var array = [];
var myImage = new Image();
for (var key in myImage) {
    if (typeof myImage[key] === null) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Null](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.12) is indeed a type. However, [`typeof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) returns `"object"` for [`null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11).

Instead, you can use a [strict equality comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.5):

```
var array = [],
    myImage = new Image();
for (var key in myImage)
  if (myImage[key] !== null)
    array.push(myImage[key]);
```

Note it's important to use strict comparison, because `undefined` and `null` are considered [abstractly equal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), but not [strictly equal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the difference between ```!=``` and ```!==``` in this case?

Comment: `===` avoids type conversion: `1 == '1'` returns `true`, while `1 === '1'` is `false`. In JavaScript `==` is the same as "equivalent to" while `===` is "identical to". The inverse versions function the same way.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/b8752e5cb1099bfcd6bb4e4f28a43e9e.png that's what I get with your code

Comment: @Revels The error in your image is not produced by my code.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof null` is `Object`. So, your condition will always be `false`.

Check it as follow:

```
if(myImage[key])
    // code
```

This will `push` only truthy elements.

Note

> typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)